# C# - Accessing HTTPS URL from .NET application (without importing server certificates) is not throwing SSL exception

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying to implement server authentication in C# (using .NET appln). I would like to achieve the following :

1. Connect to HTTPS URL using

   ```
       String sslServerHost = "https://mail.google.com";
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sslServerHost);
   ```
2. If HTTPS request fails, I would be adding the server certificate to the local windows certification store.

   ```
       X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;

       //convert the X509Certificate to an X509Certificate2 object by passing it into the constructor
       X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

       X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(storeName: StoreName.Root, storeLocation: StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

       // Code to import server certifictes to windows store.

       userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
       userCaStore.Add(cert2);
   ```

The below is the C# code that I have used for performing server authentication.

As evident from the below code snippet, I have NEITHER ignored the certificate validation NOR added the X509Certificate to the local trust store, but still I was able to establish connection to the HTTPS URL ( `WebRequest.create(url)` and `request.GetResponse()` doesn't throw any exceptions )

```
        String sslServerHost = "https://mail.google.com";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sslServerHost);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

      try
        {    
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Why is it that I'm not getting an exception when trying to access the HTTPS URL given that I have NOT added the server certificates (X509Certificate) to the local windows store.

In short, how to achieve or implement server authentication in C# where if server certificate were not added then the C# code should throw an exception.

For Java, there is a good link https://github.com/escline/InstallCert/blob/master/InstallCert.java which best describes the server authentication mechanism where if client is trying to access an HTTPS Server and if server's certificate is not present in the Java trust store, then JVM throws an exception.

This mechanism doesn't seem to hold good for .NET applications. Any help or insight would be appreciated !!

Comment: See `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`

Comment: @Eser, I'm new to .NET framework, Could you please share some supporting links ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably that `mail.google.com` is already trusted, since the certificate chain leads up to some root certificate which IS already in your certificate store (in "Trusted Root Certification Authorities").

If you want to test failure, follow a tutorial to create your own CA and certificates using something like OpenSSL. Then set up a web site in IIS with this untrusted certificate.

Answer (score 0):

According with the web request [official documentation of the web request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) The certificate could be installed in My certificate store of the current user. That might explain why it nevers throws an error. You can try to connect to a server without adding the certificate to the cert store and see if that is throwing an error.

Comment: I haven't added any certificates into certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions I have found to solve this problem involve setting a callback on `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
 MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback;

 public bool MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback(System.Object sender, 
 X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) {
     bool isOk = true;
     // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine 
     the cause.
     if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None) {
         for(int i=0; i<chain.ChainStatus.Length; i++) {
             if(chain.ChainStatus[i].Status != 
  X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown) {
                  chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
                  chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
                  chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                  chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = 
   X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;
                  bool chainIsValid = chain.Build((X509Certificate2)certificate);
                  if(!chainIsValid) {
                  isOk = false;
                 }
             }
         }
     } else {
                X509Certificate2 cert3 = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
                bool verify = cert3.Verify();
                var cert1 = new X509Certificate2(certificate);
                if (cert1.NotAfter <= DateTime.Now)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
     return isOk;
 }
```